# Looking for an alternative to canvas for IE8 (for charting purposes)

Tags: software-development, web-development, charts

I need some way of overcoming the incompatibility issues between canvas and IE8.

I'm currently using charts.js to render certain charts onto a canvas, which obviously doesn't display in IE8.

My ideal approach would be to detect compatibility on the client and then fallback to an ajax request for a jpeg version of the canvas (i.e. the chart is rendered on the server) but I can't find a way to do this. I'm currently open to any other feasible suggestions.

NOTE: I have already opted for charts.js, unfortunately switching plugins is not an option at this point.

Comment: What strange situation is forcing you to support IE8?
Also: do you have to support other browsers?
If you can adjust IE8 out of your scope/requirements your life will be much better.

Having been there and done that (my strange reason was that some parts of the  Goverment refused to upgrade/update things, ever.)
Supporting IE8 and anything else,
Almost involved developing two versions of everything.
A version that works for IE8 (but is painfully slow/laggy),
and a version for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML5Shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv). It adds (partially) HTML5 support for old browsers. You must include it as the first script in the `<head>`. You can include it only for legacy IE versions with something like this:

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.js"><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use VML -- Vector Markup Language

It support to IE8.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language

Answer (score 0):

You can use explorercanvas, it is an emulator of canvas for internet explorer. Find out how to use it here: https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions